# Стохастическая матрица (Markov chain)

Tags: java, матрицы

у меня произошла ошибка. Мне нужно создать стохастическую матрицу, например:

```
input:

0.1 0.9 0.0 // 0.1 + 0.9 + 0.0 = 1
0.5 0.4 0.1 
0.3 0.4 0.3
```

Матрица стохастическая, потому что при подсчете строк будет 1.

Моя программа работает через раз.

Моя код:

```
public class maticeStochaticka {
private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public static boolean pocetStochastic(double rozmerMatici[][]) {

    for (int i = 0; i < rozmerMatici.length; i++) {
        double sum = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < rozmerMatici[i].length; j++)
            sum = sum + rozmerMatici[i][j];
        if (sum != 1)
            return false;


    }

    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Задайте размер матрицы: ");

    int rozmerMaticiAlfa = sc.nextInt();

    double [][] rozmerMatici = new double[rozmerMaticiAlfa][rozmerMaticiAlfa];

    System.out.println("Задайте матрицу ");

    for (int i = 0; i < rozmerMaticiAlfa; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < rozmerMaticiAlfa; j++) {
            rozmerMatici[i][j] = sc.nextFloat();
        }
    }

    if (pocetStochastic(rozmerMatici)) {
        System.out.println("матрица стохастическая");
    } else {
        System.out.println("матрица не стохастическая");
    }
  }
}
```

Прошу помощи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

double имеет погрешности при операциях, поэтому его лучше сравнивать не при помощи оператора сравнения "==", а через проверку значения разницы.

```
public static boolean pocetStochastic(double rozmerMatici[][]) {

for (int i = 0; i < rozmerMatici.length; i++) {
    double sum = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < rozmerMatici[i].length; j++)
        sum = sum + rozmerMatici[i][j];
    if (Math.abs(sum - 1.0d) > 0.00001d)
        return false;
}
return true;
```

}